# Permutation representation of group described by $a_i^2=\theta^2=1, a_ia_{i+1}=\theta a_{i+1}a_i=a_{i+2}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-presentation

Let $G$ be a group with elements $\{e, a, b, c, \theta, \theta a, \theta b, \theta c \}$ where $a^2 = b^2 = c^2 = \theta$, $\theta^2 = e$, $ab = \theta b a = c$, $bc = \theta c b = a$, $ca = \theta a c = b$.

Can you find an easier-to-handle group isomorphic to $G$? (say a subgroup of $S_n$)

Comment: The smallest such $n$ is $n=8$, so that's not very helpful! It can be written as group of $2 \times 2$ matrices over the complex numbers.

Comment: That looks like the quaternion group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group you describe is the quaternion group $Q_8$.  Writing $\theta$ as $-1$ makes these relations a little easier to work with, as this notation emphasizes implicitly that $\theta$ commutes the rest of the group.
$$a^2=b^2=c^2=-1\\ \begin{array}{ccccccc}ab=-ba=c&&&bc=-cb=a&&&ca=-ac=b\end{array}$$
Usually you see $a,b,$ and $c$ written $i,j,$ and $k$, respectively.  It can be shown that it is equivalent to write these relations as $$(-1)^2=1\\i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1.$$
To see $Q_8$ as a permutation group, we use Cayley's theorem to map its generators into $S_8$.  Since $i^2=j^2=-1$ and $k=ij$, it suffices to find the images of $i$ and $j$, from which we may compute
$$
\begin{array}{rccccrcc}
1&\mapsto&\text{id}&&-1&\mapsto&(16)(24)(38)(57)\\
i&\mapsto&(1264)(3587)&&-i&\mapsto&(1462)(3785)\\
j&\mapsto&(1765)(2843)&&-j&\mapsto&(1567)(2348)\\
k&\mapsto&(1863)(2547)&&-k&\mapsto&(1368)(2745)
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Nice answer +1.

Answer (score 2):

There are only two nonabelian groups of order 8, namely $D_8$ and $Q$, the [quaternion group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group).  Your group is evidently $Q$, with $(\theta, a,b, c) = (-1, i, j, k)$.

[Cayley's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem) gives a canonical isomorphism between your group and a subgroup of $S_8$.